# How to use parameters in Nifi ExecuteSQL processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

Instead of doing a join, I want Nifi to first read all persons in a DB, and then for each person, I want it to bring the addresses. I know it is not the most efficient way, but we have some specific reasons for this.

The 'each person' part is resolved by  using SplitAvro or SplitJson processor, but how can I get the ID for that current person and use it as parameter in next ExecuteSQL processor?

I have checked something similar to what I want, however the question is a little bit old ([how to pass values dynamically in Apache NiFi from executeSQL to SelectHiveQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057483/how-to-pass-values-dynamically-in-apache-nifi-from-executesql-to-selecthiveql))

However the solution presented above seems more like a workaround for something that should be simple, I guess.

(In my case, I do not use Hive, both ExecuteSQL processor I use query on SQl Server DBs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I acknowledge this is a convoluted scenario because rather than a `JOIN`, you're doing a read/iterate/query, but if that is what you truly want to do, I think [`ExecuteSQLRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQLRecord/index.html) is what you are looking for. That processor will execute a SQL query and return the results as records using the configured `RecordWriter` controller service. You can then perform additional queries using [`LookupRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/index.html), which can connect to arbitrary data sources (although RDBMS is not currently supported) to enrich data in record format, or use `SplitRecord` to create flowfiles from the individual records and route to another `ExecuteSQLRecord` processor, which can use the incoming flowfile attributes as query parameters for SQL.

Comment: Yes, we want to avoid having duplicate records (because we would end up having to join them all by xslt, jolt, or groovy as you told me in another question), and of course real world is much more complex than just 'person/address' example. Other reason is because we will send person by person to an external SOAP webservice. I really don't get much about these RecordWriter and RecordReader other than a place to specify schema (which is optional), is there any additional docs about them? What are their main purpose? I know the question may be dumb, but I'm still new to this.

Comment: And how can I use incoming flowfile attributes as query parameters in next ExecuteSQLRecord?

Comment: You won't need query parameters, you can get all the persons in the DB using ExecuteSQLRecord, then in LookupRecord you'd point at the field containing the person ID in order to determine which person to fetch from the SOAP Service. NiFi does not currently have a SOAPLookupService however, you'd likely have to write one (either in Java or using a ScriptedLookupService).

Comment: I will actually send the data to SOAP, so a simple HTTP Post may be enough (even though I may have to read the server's return later). Andy has mentioned that LookupRecord does not support RDBMS, so this is why I'm not considering it, or does it actually supports?

Comment: Perhaps if you explain the reasons you don't want to do a `JOIN` or use a view inside your RDBMS, this will make more sense. As it stands, it sounds like you don't want the inherent negatives that come with doing this solution, but you don't want to do it the other way either. Sending data to an external service (HTTP or SOAP) doesn't require individual flowfiles throughout the flow, just at `InvokeHTTP` or still using records with `LookupRecord`. See [Mark Payne's introductory article](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) on records to understand their power.

Comment: Ok, suppose a person has addresses, cars, dogs, phones, documents, all of them are other tables, and a car has its brand, color, etc. There would be a table/view with multiple lines for each person. At first I considered the join, I was doing this way, but then we decided to avoid having to program a xslt, jolt or any other script. In short, we want to avoid scripts, that's the reason. About the webservice, it requires individual data (in SOAP body), though I see LookupRecord could be of some help. I'll check the article right now, thank you again.